# Unable to import Table in Vaadin8

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

I just tried to create a `Table` in my Vaadin 8 project:

```
Table table = new Table("The Brightest Stars");
table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
```

I have only added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    <version>8.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone help me for finding the right dependency or cause of this problem

Comment: Vaadin 8 no longer uses containers like Vaadin 7. You should either add new properties to your underlying object or use `addColumn` on grid to create custom columns

Comment: yes this addColumn worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `vaadin-compatibility-server` dependency to have access to `Table` https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8.html

Comment: this document really helped me and added Vaadin-compatibility-server dependency.It worked for me